# res.json is not a function in command prompt when the page is refreshed

Tags: node.js

This is the first time tryng nodejs, and facing "TypeError: res.json is not a function" in command prompt, 
node version: 4.4.4
npm version: 2.15.1
this is the code in my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.get('/contactlist', function(res, req){
    console.log("i received a get request");

                person1 = {
                            name:"Mahesh",
                            email:"A geek",
                            number:"22"
                        };
                person2 = {
                            name:"Ganesh",
                            email:"A nerd",
                            number:"25"
                        };
                person3 = {
                            name:"Ramesh",
                            email:"A noob",
                            number:"27"
                        };


    var contactlist = [person1, person2, person3];
    res.json(contactlist);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('server running on port 3000');
```

Help pliss..

Answer (score 6):

Function signature should be

function(req, res){}

For your app.get callback.  You have the params  reversed.

Comment: Dayum!! it was such a silly mistake, but Thanks man,yu the real MVP